# What is more precise than a new DateTime in a Dart web app?

Tags: dart

Getting a new `DateTime` isn't accurate enough for me. A date object in the browser gives me milliseconds as an integer. I'd like to be able to get a time that's more precise than the standard date object. Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `window.performance.now()` to get a monotonic, high-resolution time. The `now()` function returns a double with microseconds in the fractional.

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() {
  var time = window.performance.now();
  print(time); // 12123.24341221
}
```

Notice that `now()` is not the typical "time from the epoch". Instead, it is a delta from `window.performance.timing.navigationStart`.

The `navigationStart` field is defined as (from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#dom-performancetiming-navigationstart)):

> This attribute must return the time immediately after the user agent
>   finishes prompting to unload the previous document. If there is no
>   previous document, this attribute must return the same value as
>   fetchStart.

The `window.performance.now()` timestamp is great because it's not affected by clock skew and is more accurate than getting a new `DateTime`.

If your application is driven by `requestAnimationFrame` (and if not, why not? :) then you already have a high resolution timestamp!

The Future returned by `animationFrame` completes with a high resolution timestamp:

```dart
Future<num> animationFrame;
```

You can use it like this:

```dart
gameLoop(num highResolutionTime) {
  // stuff
  window.animationFrame.then(gameLoop);
}

main() {
  window.animationFrame.then(gameLoop);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to measure time spans use the `Stopwatch` class. It works universally (on the client and server) and should provide the best possible resolution.

```dart
var sw = new Stopwatch()..start();
doSomething();
print(sw.elapsed);
print(sw.elapsedMicroseconds);
```

Currently (as of April 2013) the Stopwatch in the browser doesn't yet use the `window.performance` functionality, but that's a [bug](https://dartbug.com/9565) and should be fixed. In the meantime you can use the workaround that was suggested by Seth.

Comment: A quick benchmark seems to indicate that Stopwatch is slower than window.perf.now() when compiled to JavaScript: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9584